# how to check whether a collection is present or not in mongodb using node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i want to check whether a collection is present or not in mongodb using node JS,if not then create one.And if collection is available then want to drop it and create new one with initial value.

Comment: Do you want to check `collection` or `document`? It's `collection` in the question title, but `document` in the question itself.

Comment: by mistake collection is replaced by document. Want to check collection

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collectionNames`:

```
db.collectionNames('exampleCollection', function(err, names) {
    console.log('The collection exists: ', names.length > 0);
});
```

Please check the [document](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collectionnames) for detail information.

Comment: This is from native Node.js MongoDB driver. I'm not familiar with monk...